# question from JR norris chapter 3

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process, renewal-processes

> Calls arrive at a telephone exchange as a Poisson process of rate $\lambda$, and the lengths of calls are independent exponential random variables of parameter $\mu$.
>
> 1. Assuming that infinitely many telephone lines are available, set up a Markov chain model for this process.  What is this model called in the literature?
> 2. Show that for large $t$ the distribution of the number of lines in use at time $t$ is approximately Poisson with mean $\lambda/\mu$.
> 3. Find the mean length of the busy periods during which at least one line is in use.
> 4. **Show that $m(t)$, the expected number of lines in use at time $t$, given that $n$ are in us at time $0$, is
>    $$  m(t) = n \mathrm{e}^{-\mu t} + \frac{\lambda}{\mu} \left( 1 - \mathrm{e}^{-\mu t}\right). $$**

The question is related to the calls arriving at a telephone exchange as a Poisson process of rate $\lambda$. I have been able to figure out the asymptotic distribution for it and also the mean length.

But I have been unable to understand as to how to go about solving the last part (4) of the question which asks: "about the expected number of lines in use at time $t$, given that $n$ are in use at time $0$"

Would be great if someone can explain to me how to solve this? (I was thinking that renewal theory could be used here, but I am not very sure if it is the best option).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Expected number of lines in use in call centre (markov process: queuing theory)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1067813/expected-number-of-lines-in-use-in-call-centre-markov-process-queuing-theory)

Comment: I also found this but I wasn't able to arrive at the right answer from it: https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~psdey/math564fa17/HW7_sol.pdf It seems like you would need to differentiate the integral equation and solve a differential equation but I didn't get anything involving $n$ that way.